# android_dynamically adding rows, how to get which row is clicked?

Tags: android

So I am dynamically adding rows to table which consist of some data (httpresponse) and buttons (like delete). How can I add onClickListener for delete button so it knows which row I want to delete?

This is part of my code, if you need more let me know:

```
    try {       

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjekt = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                Racuni novi = new Racuni();
                novi.setCode(jsonObjekt.getString("Code"));
                novi.setDate(jsonObjekt.getString("Date"));
                novi.setTotal(jsonObjekt.getString("Total"));
                niz.add(i, novi);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < niz.size(); i++) {
                TableRow redak = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                final TextView code = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                code.setText(niz.get(i).getCode());
                code.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
                TextView date = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                date.setText(niz.get(i).getDate());
                date.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
                TextView total = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                total.setText(niz.get(i).getTotal());
                total.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
                final Button print = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                print.setText("P");
                final Button delete = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                delete.setText("D");
                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
//so this is what i would like it to do, but with the proper id
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(code.getText().toString());
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://staging-api.e-poslovanje.hr/ReceiptCash/Delete" + "?id=" + id);
                        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
                        try {
                            httpclient.execute(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have deleted receipt " + code.getText().toString(), 5000).show();
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                redak.addView(code);
                redak.addView(date);
                redak.addView(total);
                redak.addView(delete);
                redak.addView(print);
                list.addView(redak);
            }
```

Comment: delete.setOnClickListener should work . but what do you mean proper id?

Comment: so id is the code of that line in which the button was clicked.
will try laymelek's advice now.

Comment: do u expect id as the index of the table row ?

Comment: does niz.get(i).getCode() has the id ?

Comment: this is what i mean by id
int id = Integer.parseInt(code.getText().toString())

Comment: then you can use tag.  delete.setTag(code.getText().toString())  and then on onClick int = delete.getTag();

Comment: what does the tag do?

Comment: just to save the object data

Comment: that solved my problem! thank you very much, can you write it as an answer so i could mark it?

Comment: Good . You can accept now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tag to hold the Id.

On the delete button , set the Id as tag

```
  tag. delete.setTag(code.getText().toString())
```

and on onClick() you can retrieve the id like..

```
 int = delete.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Row" class with Buttons and Textview. Instead of creating each button in the for loop just create a row

```
class Row{
    Button delete
    Button print
    Textview date

    public Row(){
       delete.setOnClickListener(.....);
    }
}
```

and than in mainActivity

```
 for (int i = 0; i < niz.size(); i++) {
       Row row=new Row();
  }
```

Comment: sorry just one question, about the onCreate method, so I have to write to write @Override or?

Comment: I edit my answer (sometimes getting confused between c and java :) )

Comment: thank you , will try now and will mark it if all goes ok.
thank you once again!

Comment: and how will i add it to my tablelayout then? cause it is not a view anymore?